How do I run pyqt5?
I have installed pyqt5 on my system using pip install pyqt5 but I can't figure out how to launch it. There seems to be no launcher for it.
Where does the launcher get saved?
Or
how do I launch it?
There is a folder AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin but no launcher in there either.
I installed pyqt5 on my system but can't figure out how to launch it.
I have searched everywhere leading me to believe that I can't just double click a .exe file and launch it.

There's nothing to "launch", it's a Python module, you need to use it accordingly. Check for some tutorials in order to learn about it.

What you installed was a library, it's not a program that you execute. Is it possible that you were trying to install QtCreator?
